# Word Interop Missing Headers and Footers After Section Break

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm using Word Interop to generate a bunch of documents based upon templates and UI input for my company (essentially replacing certain areas of the document with user provided values). This all seems to be working fine using the `Find.Execute()` method on every `Range in Document.StoryRanges` however, it doesn't seem to be processing headers and footers after a section break (it processes ones before perfectly fine).

How would I go about ensuring that the **entire** document is captured, headers, footers and body alike?

The relevant section of my code is below, the KVPs used are essentially find-replace pairs passed to my engine class when it's instantiated.

```
    private void ReplaceFieldsWithValues(string tempFile)
    {
        object missing = Missing.Value;
        Application wordApp = new ApplicationClass();
        wordApp.Documents.Open(tempFile);
        Document doc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
        object replaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
        foreach (Range range in doc.StoryRanges)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> referenceValue in _referenceValuePair)
            {
                Find findObject = range.Find;
                findObject.ClearFormatting();
                findObject.Text = $"&{{{referenceValue.Key}}}&";
                findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
                findObject.Replacement.Text = referenceValue.Value;
                findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            }
        }
        doc.Save();
        doc.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for Word Interop isn't the best but I found a solution, essentially get the `headerfooter` `range` objects by section rather than by `StoryRanges` and then treat them separately. I extracted my find and replace code into a separate method and now my method looks like this:

```
    private void ReplaceFieldsWithValues(string tempFile)
    {

        Application wordApp = new ApplicationClass();
        wordApp.Documents.Open(tempFile);
        Document doc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
        foreach (Range range in doc.StoryRanges)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> referenceValue in _referenceValuePair)
            {
                FindReplaceInRange(referenceValue.Key,referenceValue.Value,range,true);
            }
        }
        foreach (Section section in doc.Sections)
        {
            foreach (HeaderFooter header in section.Headers)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> referenceValue in _referenceValuePair)
                {
                    FindReplaceInRange(referenceValue.Key, referenceValue.Value, header.Range, true);
                }
            }
            foreach (HeaderFooter footer in section.Footers)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> referenceValue in _referenceValuePair)
                {
                    FindReplaceInRange(referenceValue.Key, referenceValue.Value, footer.Range, true);
                }
            }
        }
        doc.Save();
        doc.Close();
    }
```

This now appears to be working fine.